# Not able to load dataset when published on the shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to load a data set, it works fine on the local app but when I publish it I get an error.

server.R

```
library('DT')


shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$distPlot <- renderDT({bar1 <- readRDS("./Data/cohortData.RDA") })

})
```

ui.r

```
library(DT)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
bar1 <- readRDS("./Data/cohortData.RDA")
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Cohort Analysis Nisnass"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 


    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    DTOutput("distPlot")


))
```

[Output on Local Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skj8c.png)

[Output on Shiny website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGwVE.png)

logs

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:35544
2019-01-24T00:01:23.013253+00:00 shinyapps[658838]: 
2019-01-24T00:01:23.013256+00:00 shinyapps[658838]: Attaching package: ‘DT’
2019-01-24T00:01:23.013257+00:00 shinyapps[658838]: 
2019-01-24T00:01:23.014163+00:00 shinyapps[658838]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:
2019-01-24T00:01:23.014165+00:00 shinyapps[658838]: 
2019-01-24T00:01:23.014165+00:00 shinyapps[658838]:     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
2019-01-24T00:01:23.014166+00:00 shinyapps[658838]: 
2019-01-24T00:01:27.230207+00:00 shinyapps[658838]: Warning: Error in value[[3L]]: Couldn't normalize path in `addResourcePath`, with arguments: `prefix` = 'dt-core-1.10.16'; `directoryPath` = '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/DT/htmlwidgets/lib/datatables'
```

UPDATE

Datatable code

```
m<-DT::datatable(cohorts.wide,
              class = 'cell-border stripe',
              rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(
                ordering=F,
                dom = 't',
                pageLength = 12) ) %>%
  formatStyle("0",
              backgroundColor = 'lightgrey',
              fontWeight = 'bold') %>%
  formatStyle(names(cohorts.wide[c(-1,-2)]),fontWeight = 'bold',color = 'white', backgroundColor = styleInterval(breaks,colors))
```

Comment: Did you try it in the current folder?

Comment: Yes I did try that, it doesn't work.

Comment: When you upload to shinyapps, do you upload the RDA file?

Comment: yes, I did that.